# Insert jquery variable value into input hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Insert jquery variable value into input hidden field. I am unable to pass variable into hidden field. Basically i have a customize shows page. Where i have images related to different materials that we use to make shoes. If i click on image to select that material may be a buckle or thread. We get the src of image and insert into hidden field so at the end we submit form with all the images path. It's like t-shirt customize page. Just help me to insert the on click image src into hidden field.

I have code but nothing is working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.pro_img').click(function() {
        var $pro_class = $('.pro_img');
        $pro_class.removeClass('pic_select');
        $(this).addClass('pic_select');

        var imgpro = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        document.getElementById('hidden_pro_image').value = imgpro;
        //$('#hidden_pro_image').val(imgpro);

        alert(imgpro);
    });
});
```

Comment: Without your HTML it's very hard to see what the problem is.

Comment: @Screll I don't believe it an `img` since the OP says it's an "hidden input"

Comment: <div class="product-slider-row"><img class="pro_img" src="<?php echo $thumbnailSrc;?>" alt="product-1"/></div>

This code in the loop and i am all images are in slick slider. Now i want to select image by click on it and i want to get the image source so that i could store in to hidden field . Because if user select like 5 images from different materials sections. You can see here: http://luxofdubai.com/development/naurus/ i want to achieve this.

Comment: @haroonjaved When I run you code, everything works just fine, Try make the hidden input visible and inspect it and make sure the ID match.

Comment: @haroonjaved you can [edit] your question, don't post code in comments

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/9oavgLut/3/

Comment: Your code is a weird mix between plain javascript, jQuery using the `jQuery` variable and jQuery using the `$` variable. Try to stick to one style. That will make your code much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting into hidden input field based on your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pro_img').click(function() {
    
        var imgpro = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        $('#hidden_pro_image').val(imgpro);
   
        alert($('#hidden_pro_image').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="pro_img" src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1" width="100px" />

<input id="hidden_pro_image" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks brother you are right it is already working. Thanks for all. can you please tell me i have paste the link of website. I have to achieve this. I will store all image value that user selected and submit the form. Data will be exerted and i will show the all images that they have selected.

Comment: I suggest you create hidden inputs with names like 'model', 'base' for each slider and it is better send some special word instead image url, so it is easy to find witch image user selected.  And add also some class to image that user clicked on like "selected" to add some style to that class, maybe show some check icon in corner or border and opacity, so user understand witch image he have selected.